# Add pan feature to Overview Map in OpenLayers 3

Tags: gis, openlayers, openlayers-3, pan

How to pan base map with overview map in openlayers 3?

This feature works very well in openlayers 2.

Comment: Not yet. I'm planning to create a plugin for this feature.

Answer (score 0):

you can create another html element which will host the overview map, put it wherever you want, and create a new map which will have a view with same center but different zoom level.

then you'll listen to the event moveend on the first map and change the view of the second one following it:

```
yourFirstMap.on('moveend', function(evt){
    yourSecondMap.getView().setCenter(yourFirstMap.getView().getCenter());
});
```